# Auto movement when assigning a new project to team members

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a simple google sheet that has just 2 columns, Col 1 = Date assigned and Col 2 = Team Member name.

I'm looking for a script to automatically run when I change the date on the first row and move that team member to the bottom of the list and move all other rows up one place. As this will be the next person in line to get assigned the next Project. Small example below

| Date Assigned | Team Member |
| --- | --- |
| 11/29/2022 | Simon |
| 12/01/2022 | Harry |
|  | Geoff |

Geoff is left blank as currently on annual leave and therefore not available to be assigned a new project. I have a seperate table with the last date he was assigned and upon his return I will need to add the date back into the date assigned col and automatically fall in the correct order

So Example would be I assign Simon a new project and enter the date into the date assigned column and automatically he is dropped to the bottom of the list and he is replaced at the top of the list by Harry.

I used the following script from another post

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 1  && row > 1 && !as.getRange(row,col).getValue()=='') {  
    const row_new = as.getRange(row,1,1,col);
    row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(as.getLastRow()+1,1,1,col));
    as.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

This creates a new row at the bottom of the list, but doesn't take the Team member name.

Also when adding a team member back into the list after returning from annual leave I add the date he was last assigned and it simply adds a new line at the bottom and doesn't auto sort

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && !e.value) {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()
    try {
      vs.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[0] && b[0]) {
          e.source.toast('a');
          return new Date(a[0]).valueOf() - new Date(b[0]).valueOf();
        } else if (!a[0] && b[0]) {
          e.source.toast('b')
          return +1;
        } else if (!b[0] && a[0]) {
          e.source.toast('c')
          return -1;
        } else {
          e.source.toast('d')
          return 0;
        }
      })
    }
    catch (err) {
      e.source.toast(err)
    }
    sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    sh.getRange(2, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  }
}
```

Before Editing first line:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Date Assigned | Team Member |
| 2 | 10/01/2022 | Geoff |
| 3 | 11/29/2022 | Simon |
| 4 | 12/01/2022 | Harry |

After removing first date:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Date Assigned | Team Member |
| 2 | 11/29/2022 | Simon |
| 3 | 12/1/2022 | Harry |
| 4 |  | Geoff |

Comment: I've added your code and get the following error when I run it in the app script - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')
onEdit @ Code.gs:2. Also when I make a date change nothing happens, but this could be to do with the error.

Comment: It sounds like you tried to run the function from the script editor and that cannot be done unless you provide an intermediate function and supply the event object like the onEdit trigger does.  Or you can simply do as I do, which is to debug the code by editing the appropriate sheet in the appropriate way.